# My images have been deleted after an app update

Tags: ios, ipad, file

I'm trying to update my iPad app using TestFlight and the problem I have is that the images which I'm  storing are being deleted when I update the app.

I'm using this code to downloading and later store the images:

```
NSData *responseData = [request responseData]; 
UIImage *imageURL = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:responseData];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageURL)];
[data1 writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];
[imageURL release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saving your image directly over (not inside) Documents directory. It should not even save the images in the first place. Instead create a subpath under Documents directory and save your file there.

```
NSString* imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"someImage.png"];
[data1 writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

The link which at the end solves my trouble was:

[Problem with NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains And Persistent Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007494/problem-with-nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-and-persistent-data)

Thanks anyway!!